# jquery removeAttr('class') still retaining elements of the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am struggling with the removeAttr('class') and removeClass() functions in jquery.

```
removeAttr('class') OR removeClass();
```

I have three buttons, of which I would like 2 to be disabled (unclickable) when information is entered into a input text form field.

I have entered my current code into the following jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/robgagliano/9ttfkw5t/

You will see from the example, the css is changing however the buttons are not disabling (i.e they are still clickable).

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to enable the buttons when the user type?

Comment: did you try the `disabled` property?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the event handler from the buttons by removing the class 'on'?

Comment: @LeoJavier - I am trying to disable the second and third button when the user types into the text field.

Comment: check my answer http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/9ttfkw5t/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keyup` event, and a delegated event listener

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#user-input1").on('keyup change', function() {
      if ($(this).val() != '')
          $("#id2,#id3").removeClass('on');

      else if ($(this).val() == '')
          $("#id2,#id3").addClass('on');;
  });

    $("body").on("click",".on", function(){ // delegated event listener
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('value');
        $('.select').removeClass('currentttt');
        $(".options").hide();
        $(".table1").show();
        $("#option4").show();
        $("#"+tab_id).show();
        $(this).addClass('currentttt');

    });
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/9ttfkw5t/3/)

Comment: add "change" in the event listener, `$("#user-input1").on('keyup change', function() {`

Comment: Good Answer! Take a look at the demo I was working on if you need another example of how to do this. It's a bit more concise. http://jsfiddle.net/tvbyn4ss/1/

Comment: @davcs86 thank you for your prompt response, and all others who provided feedback.  The delegated event listener was what I was really after, and the keyup event was a bonus.  You learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/9ttfkw5t/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#user-input1").on('keyup', function() {
          if ($(this).val() != '')
              $("#id2,#id3").removeAttr('class').addClass('select');
          else if ($(this).val() == '')
              $("#id2,#id3").removeAttr('class').addClass('select on');
      });

    $('.on').click(function(){
     var tab_id = $(this).attr('value');
        $('.select').removeClass('currentttt');
        $(".options").hide();
        $(".table1").show();
        $("#option4").show();
        $("#"+tab_id).show();
        $(this).addClass('currentttt');

    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to disable as soonb as user types in the textbox use the **keyup()** event handler

```
$("#user-input1").keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != '')
          $("#id2,#id3").removeAttr('class').addClass('select');
      else if ($(this).val() == '')
          $("#id2,#id3").removeAttr('class').addClass('select on');
  });
```

[Check out this fisddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7ezj6t5/)

Answer (score 0):

Removing a class does not remove events that are bound to that element. So add:

```
$("#id2,#id3").unbind();
```

When you don't want it to fire anymore.

See this SO answer for clarification:

[JQuery Class Selector still firing after removeClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976012/jquery-class-selector-still-firing-after-removeclass)

Note that you'll have to re-bind the events again if you want to be able to click on the 2nd and 3rd div after they have been unbind-ed.  See: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

An alternate approach would be this (not tested):

[How to disable and then enable onclick event on <div> with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982642/how-to-disable-and-then-enable-onclick-event-on-div-with-javascript)